# Decripting ASPXAUTH cookie, that cames from an external webforms app, in .NETCoreApp, Version 1.0

Tags: cookies

Is there a way to Decrypt an .ASPXAUTH cookie in .NETCoreAPP v1.0 (Not ASP.NETCore) ?
I mention that I know the machinekey(decryption and validation keys).

If you know a way how this can be done please respond.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I realized that this cannot be done. 
So I switched back to MVC 5 .Net Framework 4.5.2.

There is a FormAuthentication.Decrypt() method that is doing all the work for you.